# Using grep with count_if (EXPSS package in R)

Tags: r, count, grepl

I'm trying to count instances where a certain string appears in a dataframe (this will be a sub-string, i.e. "blue" will appear within a larger block of text), and then summarize those counts by another field.

Here's the code:

```
    totals_by_county <- county_data %>%
      group_by(county_data$county)%>%
      summarise(number_occurences = count(grepl('blue', county_data$color,ignore.case = TRUE))) 
    totals_by_county
```

And I get this error:

> no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "logical"

Is there a way to do this in the method I'm trying to use above?

Comment: i think you can use sum(grepl('blue',color,ignore.case = TRUE))

Comment: But if 'blue' is one of your colors, then df %>% count(county,color) will work?

Comment: That seems to give the same value for numer_occurences, for every county.

Comment: you cannot have "county_data$color" inside the summarize function

Comment: You call `count` from `dplyr`. It is create table of counts, not single numeric as you expect.

Comment: do you mean `str_count`, instead of `count(grepl(...))`?

Comment: I think I do want str_count, I think, since i'm aggregating instances of whether that string is present.  However, if I do str_count, I get: 'column must be length 1'

Comment: to be clear, I want to first group by county, and for each county, sum the number of instances where "blue" is contained in the larger string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `grepl`:

```
totals_by_county <- county_data %>%
    group_by(county) %>%
    summarise(number_occurences = sum(grepl('blue', color, ignore.case = TRUE)))
```

or, with `count_if` from `expss`:

```
totals_by_county <- county_data %>%
    group_by(county) %>%
    summarise(number_occurences = count_if(perl('blue', ignore.case = TRUE), color))
```

UPDATE with reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(expss)

county_data = data.frame(
    county = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
    color = c("blue-blue", "red", "orange-blue", "yellow", "green"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


county_data %>%
    group_by(county) %>%
    summarise(number_occurences = count_if(perl('blue', ignore.case = TRUE), color)) 

# A tibble: 2 x 2
# county number_occurences
# <chr>              <int>
# 1 A                  2
# 2 B                  0
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems like the right approach, but for some reason, it's giving me the same (wrong) counts, no matter what string I search for.